# C# List all keys under specific amazon S3 prefix

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

Using ListObjectRequest from ASWS SDK in C#, we can list all the keys and prefixes within a amazon S3 prefix as following:

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();           
request.BucketName = "backetname"; //Amazon Bucket Name
request.Prefix = "SALES/20220222"; //Amazon S3 Folder path           
do
{
    ListObjectsResponse response = _client.ListObjects(request);//_client - AmazonS3Client
}
```

**Output**

```
SALES/20220222
SALES/20220222/1300
SALES/20220222/1500
SALES/20220222/1800
SALES/20220222/1300/sales.scv
SALES/20220222/1500/sales.scv
SALES/20220222/1800/sales.scv
```

Is it possible to achieve list below?

**Desired output:**

```
SALES/20220222/1300/sales.scv
SALES/20220222/1500/sales.scv
SALES/20220222/1800/sales.scv
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html